Why can I call a pointer's IsValidLowLevel() function without a null check?
Good practice in UE5 is to make sure you're not calling a function on a nullptr.
One method of doing this would be calling the pointers IsValidLowLevel() function like follows...
if (ActorPtr->IsValidLowLevel())
{
    ActorPtr->DoSomething();
}

But why does this actor pointer have guaranteed access to this function if it is indeed a nullptr? Shouldn't the program crash if you call a function on a nullptr the same as if I called the ActorPtr's DoSomething() function? And is there a difference in how these functions are called?
I'm also aware that there are other and probably better ways to nullcheck since it also does a bunch of other checks that might not be necessary, but I'm just curious why you can even do this in the first place.
I've checked out UE5's documentation on this function, but it's super helpful and says that it does a nullcheck and doesn't go into how it does it.

I used to do something similar in one of my APIs, but had to change it -- the problem is, the compiler is free to assume that whenever you call x->y(), that x will always be non-NULL, so any tests for validity of the this pointer you might want to do inside y() can and likely will be optimized away as unnecessary.  The only way to make this sort of test work reliably is to make it a static method or free-standing function instead (e.g. bool IsValidLowLevel(const Actor * actorPtr) {return (actorPtr != NULL);})

I'd say if (ActorPtr->IsValidLowLevel()) should probably be if (ActorPtr && ActorPtr->IsValidLowLevel()).

While many people will tell you that calling a method on a null object is UB (and they are right), in practice, compilers may generate reasonable, non crashing code, which behaves predicably, for formal UB. if ActorPtr actually points to valid memory you can read, but NOT to a UObject, then the generated code only accesses a trivial member at a fixed offset to the object (the object index), and it is extremely unlikely that the object in the global  table at that index is the passed in object. This is why the method says "return true if this appears to be a valid object"

... IsValidLowLevel will definitely crash if the given pointer doesn't point to a valid object, and if it doesn't point to readable memory, or the it is misaligned, or the compiler inserts additional validation checks for calling a method with a null pointer (or potentially for other reasons as well which I cannot see). But it is NOT guaranteed to crash, nor is the check being true a guarantee that the pointer points to a valid object

To cover a few of these replies! IsValidLowLevel Does not crash if the pointer is indeed null, which is why this question is a thing in the first place. and if (ActorPtr->IsValidLowLevel()) is identical to doing if (ActorPtr && ActorPtr->IsValidLowLevel()) are achieving the same thing, since IsValidLowLevel() is used for null checking

@Wardy "IsValidLowLevel Does not crash if the pointer is indeed null" - It may not crash currently with your current compiler and build flags, but it is invalid according to the C++ standard and can stop working at any moment. That's the nature of undefined behaviour; any behaviour is acceptable - including behaving as you expect - but there are no guarantees about the behaviour you observe currently or what behaviour you may observe in the future. So just don't write code with UB. Just testing code and observing its behaviour is not sufficient to declare that a program is valid C++.

See Does calling a method on a NULL pointer which doesn't access any data ever fail? for some discussion on this point.

Dereferencing a nullptr is undefined behavior. A crash is not guaranteed, anything (literally) is allowed to happen and the compiler is not required to warn you about it - it can just assume it never happens (because if it did, that would mean you break the rules and then it's allowed to do whatever). And if the function checks for nullptr internally, then that is just pointless since this is not allowed to ever be nullptr inside a member function, so any sensible optimizing compiler is just going to optimize away any such check.
What you want in your current situation is probably if (ActorPtr && ActorPtr->IsValidLowLevel()).

This is the logic that I was following too, but the thing is that the function does work if the pointer is indeed null. I think one of the commenters was onto something saying that the function looks at the area in memory that the pointer is taking up and sees if it "appears to be a uobject". But your logic is exactly why I was so confused about why this function works in the first place because it goes against everything I was taught in the basics.

@wardy "but the thing is that the function does work if the pointer is indeed null" - UB allows anything to happen, including calling the function and behaving as you expect - that's included in the set of "anything". That doesn't mean that the code is not broken though and that the behaviour cannot change at any moment (change of compiler, change of compiler optimization level, change of compiler version, etc etc). The code is invalid/broken and you can not rely on whatever behaviour you are currently observing.

Thanks for the quick reply again! If this is the case then I do not understand why Unreal Engine would have a built in function meant for null checking, if UB is going to occur whenever the pointer is actually null instead of it being a static bool function in which to place a pointer and do a null check on it that way

@wardy "I do not understand why Unreal Engine would have a built in function meant for null checking" - I don't know either, but I can think of a few potential reasons; Incompetence. Lazyness. Ignorance. "it seems to work for me with my tool-chain"ism (which is pretty much the same as the others).

@Wardy For more in depth information I'd strongly advice that you read the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub page I linked to (in full) and also read all of the very good articles that are linked at the end. That should give you a good overview of UB in C++ (and C; but that's still relevant) and the dangers involved in messing with it. :-) Modern compilers exploit UB heavily and optimize based on it (not occurring) quite a lot - knowing about it is really important IMHO.

Your help's been appreciated! I'll give them a check :)

@Wardy See also https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 (and part 2 & 3).
